# QCombobox text aligment

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Привет! Подскажите, как текст в `QCombobox` поставить по центру. В гугле основной вариант предлагают следующий:

`QComboBox comboBox;
comboBox.setEditable(true);
comboBox.lineEdit()->setReadOnly(true);
comboBox.lineEdit()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
comboBox.addItem("Nemesis");
comboBox.addItem("Erebus");
comboBox.addItem("Nix");
for (int i = 0 ; i < comboBox.count() ; ++i) {
comboBox.setItemData(i, Qt::AlignCenter, Qt::TextAlignmentRole);`

но `comboBox.lineEdit()->setReadOnly(true);` и `comboBox.lineEdit()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);` не могут выполнится т.к. у lineEdit() таких методов нет. Подскажите, как быть?

P.S Qt 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё правильно предлагают, проблема скорее всего заключается в том, что вы забыли добавить `#include <QLineEdit>`.

Comment: спасибо, помогло!